# Add exclude apache.commons.lang3 from net.sourceforge.dynamicreports

Tags: maven, dynamic-reports, apache-stringutils

I want to add a dependency in my project to use dynamic report, i found this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but when i add it to my `pom.xml`, i got this error :`The method isNoneBlank(String) is undefined for the type StringUtils` error in `StringUtils.isNoneBlank(...)`.

I think it's a conflit in versions of lang3

how can i add an exclude for `commons.lang3`?

Comment: Commons lang3 classes are in different package. How you are getting version mismatch? Where and when do you see this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you can define an exclusion

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons.lang3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- other exclusions ... -->
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html