# How to use same lib for compile and run at Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, runtime-error, nosuchmethoderror

I have a maven project that was imported as java project. When I run it, I get

```
Handling error: NestedServletException, Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.addDays(Ljava/util/Date;I)Ljava/util/Date;
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42097/3026886) I got this line:

```
[Loaded org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils from file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.0/commons-lang-2.0.jar]
```

But at `pom.xml` it's:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Considering I have this libs at `Java Build Path`:

[image]

and

[image]

How could I resolve this problem? Where can I assured compare my run vs compile libs?

**EDIT**

this is the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-lang`:

```
    [INFO] com.companyName.gestao.projectName:projectName-webapp:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] \- com.companyName.gestao.projectName:projectName-business:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
    [INFO]    +- com.companyName.commons.utils:companyName-commons-utils:jar:1.14.5:compile
    [INFO]    |  \- softdes:softdes-all:jar:1.6.23:compile
    [INFO]    |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile (version managed from 2.0)
    [INFO]    \- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:companyName-6.4.0.4:compile
    [INFO]       \- org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:jar:1.3.3:compile
    [INFO]          +- org.codehaus.castor:castor-core:jar:1.3.3:compile
    [INFO]          |  \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile - version managed from 2.0; omitted for duplicate)
    [INFO]          \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile - version managed from 2.0; omitted for duplicate)
```

Running the same command at `business` subproject(at same directory level that `webapp` project):

```
[INFO] com.companyName.gestao.projectName:projectName-business:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.companyName.commons.utils:companyName-commons-utils:jar:1.14.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- softdes:softdes-all:jar:1.6.23:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.0:compile
```

So `webapp` depends upon `business` that depends upon `companyName-commons-utils` that depends upon `softdes-all` that depends upon `commons-lang` version 2. But `webapp` must use `commons-lang` version 2.6.

Can I accomplish this by changing dependency order at `pom.xml`?

**SECOND EDIT**

After adding `<exclusion>` to `commons-lang` at `business` dependency, I run dependency tree maven as stated above. Now, besides `BUILD SUCCESS`, maven doesn't have any tree printed, as below:

```
        PS C:\workspace\projectName-dev\webapp> mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-lang
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Conciliador - webapp 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ conciliador-webapp ---
    [WARNING] Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 8.629s
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu May 17 13:21:08 BRT 2018
    [INFO] Final Memory: 29M/494M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PS C:\workspace\projectName-dev\webapp>
```

I discovered that `commons-lang` dependency is inside `dependencyManagement` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280943/3026886) and `DateUtils` is still loaded from 2.0 version Jar. What could be done?

Comment: There's a class loader order issue. Some other jar is using 2.0 version and loading it at startup, then at runtime it fails. Print the dependency tree to spot which dependency is including version 2.0. Then exclude it.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, I added the info you request. How would you continue to solve this problem? Thanks for you suggestion in fist place, showed the exact cause problem.

Comment: Welcome!. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29144226/2834978) is an example on how to exclude a dep.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, I added what happened after I added exclusion on a dependency. It's stranger because now I can't understand why is still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LuisMuñoz stated on comments, I added exclusions to all possible libs using older dependencies. Even with this Eclipse insisted in using older versions of it. I went to project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export and top prioritized over everything else my newer dependency version 2.6. After this it worked. Sounds like pom definitions doesn't matter at all if is Eclipse configs that have the final word.

Comment: pom definitions do matter. You build with Eclipse for development convenience but your app might be built by jenkins or some other method. To compare, build on command line and you'll see that pom rules :) .